Co-ordinate basis vector of polynomial
I am working through a memo and found the following question.

The coordinate basis vector of p relative to the basis $S = \left\{p_1, p_2, p_3\right\}$
where $p=2+2x+ 2x^2$, $p_1=1+x$, $p_2=1+x^2$, $p_3 =x + x^2$
are

And the correct answer is given as $(2,2,2)$.
Surely the answer should be $(1,1,1)$? If not, please help me understand why it is $(2,2,2)$.

You are correct; it should be $(1,1,1)$ because
$$
1p_1 + 1  p_2 + 1 p_3 = p.
$$
